# Input button combined with a background AND a sprite for hover

Tags: css, button, input, sprite

hello I have some misunderstanding about css sprite. I'd like to have one button like bellow (hover with the green checkmark. It works like a charm if i use these 2 pictures combined into a sprite with background url and background position.

[link to the picture explanation](http://imgh.us/cancel2.png)
*sorry not enough reputation to post pictures*

But my issue is that button is composed with a background

and I put on it a sprite with the checkmark (false)

But no way to do the same but with hover status (true checkmark)

My HTML

```
<div class="sprite sprite-novalid"> </div>
<input type="button" id="cancel" value="Cancel" name="button" onclick="" class="btn" title="Cancel [Alt+X]">
```

My CSS : for the background button without any checkmark

```
.btn,input[type="button"],.btn{ 
background-color:#ECF1F4;
background-image:url(http://);
border-color:#ABC3D7;
color:#000000}

.btn, input{
border-radius:12px;
height: 31px;
width: 180px}
```

My css : for the sprite

```
.sprite {
background: url(http://); 
no-repeat;}
```

My css : for the false checkmark (grey)

```
.sprite-novalid {
width: 19px;
height: 16px;
background-position: -31px 2px;
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
bottom: 134px;
left: 21px;}
```

For the hover css, I put nothing because so much errors

Thanks for everyone for advices, or/and put me on the right track.

Best regards
Dimitri

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure that I undertand you issue, however you can make :hover shift your sprite up/downwards ..

```
.btn:hover{
width: 19px:
height: 16px;
background-position: ?px ?px;
/* some other styles you want*/
}
```

so all you need is a sprite with all relevant images (id make the entire button and its variations in one sprite) and then shift them around when needed..then you need a css class for the inactive button, and one for :hover. this guy explains it very well http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-simple-button-with-css-image-sprites

I hope this helps - otherwise a fiddle demo would be nice in future questions and if your issue is not resovled by the time you see my answer, please make one for me to see :)